# Laravel 5.1 - AJAX POST - Getting Error 407

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I want to have a AJAX post request. So, what I have one is like it-

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var baseURL = $('meta[name=base_url]').attr("content")+'/';
    var lastClicked = 0;
    var token = $('meta[name=csrf_token]').attr("content");

    $( "#button_yes,#button_no" ).click(function()
    {
        var now = new Date();
        if(now - lastClicked > 10000)
        {
            lastClicked = now;
            console.log('Done');
            $.ajax(
            {
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
                url: baseURL+"add_votes",
                success: function(result)
                {
                    alert(result);
                    console.log(result);
                    console.log(token);
                },
                method: "POST",
                data:
                {
                    _token:         token,
                    uuid : $('meta[name=webniar_ID]').attr("content")
                },
            });
        }
    });
});
```

So, more specifically-

```
            $.ajax(
            {
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
                url: baseURL+"add_votes",
                success: function(result)
                {
                    alert(result);
                    console.log(result);
                    console.log(token);
                },
                method: "POST",
                data:
                {
                    _token:         token,
                    uuid : $('meta[name=webniar_ID]').attr("content")
                },
            });
```

But I am getting a **407 Error**

[image]

[image]

Can anyonehelp me please?

Comment: Did you check what the 407 error is? http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E407.html

Comment: Yes, I have already checked it and can't find any solution.

Can u please help @Vladimir Serykh

Comment: This doesn't look like a Laravel issue; it looks like a problem with your server config. Specifically, look at your response headers: what type of server is "GFE/2.0"? I googled it, & came up with something called "Google Front End". What is that? we need more details on your server configuration.

Comment: Are you trying to interface with a form (or something else) on Google Docs?

Comment: No, just want to send a post request to add something in DB

Comment: Edit your question to include the details of your web server - what server are you using? what version? where is it hosted? We can start with that, and then ask more questions.